# Can I Change the Colorway of the Query Editor on the Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am currently taking Google's Data Analytics course and they mentioned (to make things easier) we are using BigQuery within the Google Cloud Platform and I have been messing around with it for a bit.

I'm new to a lot of this (SQL & coding in general) so I apologize in advance if I'm not explaining well. But basically, I was wondering if I can choose a color scheme within BigQuery? So, inside the editor, when I use a double dash ( -- ) to add comments, the comments are red. When I type out `SELECT` `FROM` and `WHERE`, they turn blue in color within the editor. When I type out a 'String', the string becomes green. Am I able to change to a different color scheme where the examples above are different colors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extensions from your browser can probably change this. Dark Reader I think allows you to have a dark theme with a slightly different color scheme for syntax highlighting.